# Blockchain app says I'm over my limit

Tags: error, blockchain-wallet-app

I have the Blockchain app on my iPhone which I've been using regularly for years but which in fact I haven't used for the last 4 months. It currently has around $2000 worth of BTC in my private wallet. I have just gone to make a purchase for goods of around $50. I click on Send, select Private Key Wallet, enter the recipient's address but as I type $50 it tells me in red that I am trying to send an amount over my limit. Can anyone tell me what's happening with this?

Answer (score 1):

Solved! I went to my profile and under Security I saw the Backup Phrase wasn't confirmed (even though I had made a note of the phrase when I first opened an account). I clicked on Backup Phrase, took a note of the words (same as I had written down) and then answered the question - what is your 2nd, 3rd and 11th word. After that is put "confirmed" by Backup Phrase. I was then able to send btc.

I'd suggest to the developers that they put a more meaningful message than "over your limit" if this is in fact the issue. And why would it let me send $5 but not $50?! Some rule written somewhere in the software that isn't brought to the user's attention.

Comment: To make suggestions to the developers of an app you'd need to post your suggestions somewhere those developers read. This self-help Q&A site isn't an official channel for communicating with employees of Blockchain.com or any of the many other businesses providing Bitcoin related services.